# Лагает клава на ноуте

Tags: клавиатура, железо

Доброго времени суток, собственно такой вопрос. Юсб клава тормозит в загрузчике, родная залита, умерла и отцеплена. Т.е. при загрузке довольно неудобно выбирать между линем и виндой, жутчайше тормозит. В ОС всё норм, в биосе то же нормально реагирует, может кто сталкивался, а то даже лайвку не загрузить. Ноут HP 4525s, биос F.20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в биусе опцию USB RMH. Если она есть отключите должно помочь.

Comment: Приветствую, такой опции нет. По поводу БитКода не знал, прошу прщения=)

Comment: Еще хотелось бы узнать расшифровку RMH, если не сложно)

Comment: Rate Matching Hub. Очень в общем эта опция включает энергосбережение для usb когда к порту подключено устройство с небольшой скоростью передачи данных